# Randomising a number then displaying a corresponding cell on workbook open

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon. I have tried multiple methods now to achieve this. In essence the code works when I run it, however, it doesn't seem to do it when the Workbook opens as it should. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Basically in rows 5-28 there are random strings, and I want cell G4 to show one of the random strings every time the workbook is opened.

I think I might be along the right lines, but am I missing anything obvious?

Many thanks

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    wbOpenEventRun = True    
    Dim MyValue
    MyValue = Int((28 * Rnd) + 5)
    Sheets("Hints & Tips").Range("G4") = Cells(MyValue, 7)
End Sub
```

Comment: I just think you need (23*rnd) + 5,  what is the problem currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Randomize    'As Suggested by John Coleman
    wbOpenEventRun = True    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Hints & Tips")
    ws.Range("G4").Value = ws.Range("G" & Int((23 * Rnd()) + 5)).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason it did it the first time I opened the file, then every subsequent time I opened it the row was set as 17 and did not change (opened 10 times)

Comment: Sorry, try with parenthesis after Rnd, like so:  `ws.Range("G" & Int((23 * Rnd()) + 5)).Value`

Comment: @OliEshmade You would need to use `Randomize` as the first line of the sub so that it reseeds the random number generator (from the system clock) every time the workbook is opened.

Comment: @JohnColeman That has made it work perfectly. Thank you! Very helpful, and an interesting solution.

Comment: Also @Carmelid Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to assign something to the Range object, not to the cell's value. Read the Value property of the source cell and write that to the Value property of the destination:

```
Sheets("Hints & Tips").Range("G4").Value = Sheets("SourceSheet").Cells(MyValue, 7).Value
```

It's best to also specify which sheet is the source of the data, or it will depend on which sheet is active at the time the macro runs - unless that's the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween()`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    wbOpenEventRun = True    
    Dim MyValue
    MyValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(5,28)
    Sheets("Hints & Tips").Range("G4") = Cells(MyValue, 7)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Apologies I marked the other answer as correct; your solution worked perfectly also. it was the term Randomize that solved it.

Comment: @OliEshmade No need to apologize. It is good to know of multiple solutions. One of the reasons I like using `RandBetween` is precisely because it handles the reseeding automatically. On the other hand, I suspect that using `Rnd()` is probably a bit quicker.